# python spark write timestamp as long in elasticsearch

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, elasticsearch-plugin

im reading data from jdbc source and writing it directly into elastic search index. when I queried the data in ES I saw that all timestamp fields in my dataframe transformed to long

Below is to save

```
 spark_df1.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
.option('es.index.auto.create', 'true')
.option("es.write.operation", "index")
.option('es.host','localhost')
.option('es.mapping.date.rich',"True")
.option('es.mapping.id', 'Ticket')
.mode("append")
.save("index_esche/type")
```

when I run spark_df.printSchema()

```
|-- Createdon: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- Updatedon: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- Resolvedon: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Does your mapping pre-exist? You should define `Createdon` for example as date type in elasticsearch mapping.

Comment: How cani give mapping as an input while calling the spark save to ES method? And is there any way we can do using dynamic mapping created by elasticsearch?